# double image occuring

Tags: image-stacking

What's happening here with my dslr camera?[image]

Comment: How do you expect us to even have a clue if you do not tell us what your camera settings were for this photograph, at  minimum we need f-stop shutter speed.  You need to give us a detailed description of what you did when you took this photograph and what your camera settings were.

Comment: Do you have a UV filter on the lens? Were you shooting handheld or on a tripod?

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess:

You used a tripod but it is one that moves every time you touch anything?

You pressed the shutter button directly, rather than using a remote release or the self-timer?

The dimmer circle is the moon where it was in the frame when the shutter first opened. The brighter circle is the the moon where it was in the frame once the camera stabilized.

Comment: That sounds a fair guess. I'm intrigued, though, by the little pattern of 3 dots, which haven't moved in the same direction. Passing plane?

Comment: @Tetsujin - On my phone's screen the two patterns appear to have moved the same distance as the double image, perhaps a slow moving object (bug or dust speck / dandy lion seed).

Comment: same distance, approx, yet different angle & no blur in between.

Comment: could be lens flare?

Comment: Flare of the type known as ghosting is usually reversed. This looks more like a "double image' caused by multiple camera positions during the exposure.

Answer (score -2):

Photo engineers try to design cameras that deliver a faithful image, but no cigar. Today’s cameras are good but not perfect. These camera  things are loaded with glass. We are talking glass lenses consisting of multiple elements, each with two polished surfaces. Additionally, the image sensor sports a protective cover glass that does double duty filtering out unwanted light frequencies. And don’t forget the SLR’s reflex mirror. The bottom line, each and every surface is polished and thus they reflect light. Now all this reflected stuff within the optical path is bad stuff. We are now taking flare light that reduces contrast. We are also talking about internal reflections that produce ghost images. To mitigate, all these polished surfaces are coated, some multi-coated. The job of the coating is to diminish reflections. Try as they might, the photo engineers need to do better.

Comment: I don't think this is ghosting. The dimmer image is not reversed.